# When an html checkbox is selected disable other checkboxes

Tags: html

Is there a way to disable some checkboxes from being used when another html checkbox is selected? Can this be done only with html or do I need other tools also?

Comment: you need some JS code

Comment: You could use radio boxes for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this but with using javascript.

```
<form method="post" action="/Tests/Post">  
<fieldset>  
<legend>Choose one only</legend>  
<input type="checkbox" name="choose" value="Iphone" onclick="return ValidateSelection();">Iphone<br>  
<input type="checkbox" name="choose" value="Samsung" onclick="return ValidateSelection();">Samsung<br>  
<input type="checkbox" name="choose" value="OnePlus" onclick="return ValidateSelection();">OnePlus<br>  
    <br>  
<input type="submit" value="Submit now">  
</fieldset>  
</form>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
function ValidateSelection()  
{  
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("choose");  
var numberOfCheckedItems = 0;  
for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)  
{  
    if(checkboxes[i].checked)  
        numberOfCheckedItems++;  
}  
if(numberOfCheckedItems > 1)  
{  
    alert("You can't select more than one ");  
    return false;  
}  
}  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your file.html body should be:

```
<body>

  <input type="checkbox" id="box-1" onChange="disableBox2()" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="box-2"/>
  <input type="checkbox" class="box-2"/>

  <script>
    function disableBox2(){
      var boxList = document.getElementsByClassName('box-2');
      if(document.getElementById('box-1').checked) {
         for(let i = 0;i < boxList.length; i++){
             boxList[i].disabled = true;
         }
      }
      else {
         for(let i = 0;i < boxList.length; i++){
             boxList[i].disabled = false;
         }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
```